# how to make a function version of this

Tags: lua

I made a program on Lua to display a table content, it also display a content of a table that is inside this table

```lua
for i in pairs(v) do
    if type(v[i])=="table" then
        for j in pairs(v[i]) do
             if type(v[i][j])=="table" then
                 print("...")
             else
                 print(i,j,v[i][j])
             end
        end
    else
        print(i,v[i])
    end
end
```

My question is, is possible to make a version function of the above that work with undefined number of table inside table like `{{{1},1},1}` showing something like?

1 1 1 1

1 2 1

2 1

Comment: Yes it is possible using recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive function. See the *globals* example in the [Lua online demo](https://www.lua.org/demo.html), reproduced below. Call `dump` with your table instead of `_G`.

```
-- globals.lua
-- show all global variables

local seen={}

function dump(t,i)
    seen[t]=true
    local s={}
    local n=0
    for k in pairs(t) do
        n=n+1 s[n]=k
    end
    table.sort(s)
    for k,v in ipairs(s) do
        print(i,v)
        v=t[v]
        if type(v)=="table" and not seen[v] then
            dump(v,i.."\t")
        end
    end
end

dump(_G,"")
```